# How to make the width of a div in the middle responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float, responsive

Hi I'd like to know how to implement in CSS a way to make the width of a div in the middle of two other divs auto adjustable.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.left,
.right,
.middle {
  float: left; // or display:inline i don't know... you tell me
}
.left {
  width: 50px;
}
.right {
  width: 60px;
}
.middle {
  width: "...fill the container...";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

So as you can see, the container is responsive, and the divs on the left and on the right are fixed. I need to have the div in the middle responsive so that it fills the container.

You can think of it like two sidebars fixed and the main content responsive in the middle of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Flexbox

<sub>(**IE10+**)</sub>
Using `flex` you could add `display: flex;` to the `.container` and `flex:1;` to the `.middle`.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}


.container{
  display:flex;
}

/* your styles */
.left  {width:50px; background: #0bf;}
.middle{flex:1;     background: #fb0;}
.right {width:60px; background: #bf0;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">50</div>
  <div class="middle">remaining width</div>
  <div class="right">60</div>
</div>
```

---

### Using `calc()`

<sub>(**IE9+**)</sub>
Using `calc` makes the browser do the calculations for you

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}


.container > *{
  float: left;
}

/* your styles */
.left  {width:50px;                background: #0bf;}
.middle{width:calc(100% - 110px);  background: #fb0;}
.right {width:60px;                background: #bf0;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">50</div>
  <div class="middle">remaining width</div>
  <div class="right">60</div>
</div>
```

---

### Using `display:table`

<sub>(All browsers)</sub>
You could simply use `display` `table` and `cell`:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}


.table{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
}

/* your styles */
.left  {width:50px; background: #0bf;}
.middle{width:auto; background: #fb0;}
.right {width:60px; background: #bf0;}
```

```html
<div class="table container">
  <div class="cell left">50</div>
  <div class="cell middle">remaining width</div>
  <div class="cell right">60</div>
</div>
```

---

### Using floats

<sub>(All browsers)</sub>
Or you could simply use the `.container` background color to act as the `.middle` "background" color....

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}

.container{background: #fb0; overflow:auto; height:100%;}

/*your styles*/
.left  {float:left;  width:50px; height:100%; background: #0bf;}
.middle{overflow:auto;}
.right {float:right; width:60px; height:100%; background: #bf0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">50</div>
  <div class="right">60</div>
  <div class="middle">remaining width<br>(not actually, the background is .container's)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Flexbox` just set `flex: 1` on `.middle` div

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.right {
  width: 60px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.middle {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="middle">Middle</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use `Flexbox` you can use `float` and `calc`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.container > div {
  float: left;
}
.left {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.right {
  width: 60px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.middle {
  width: calc(100% - (50px + 60px));
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Div</div>
  <div class="middle">Div</div>
  <div class="right">Div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about the browser-crossing? Is this little or very compatible?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan  Nope `:)`

Comment: @ErnieBob see for yourself: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox so forget about IE<10

Comment: Isn't there a way without flex? Just playing with the regular displays and floats or widths?

Comment: If you want you can use `.middle{ width: calc(100% - 110px); }` but that's than just one IE version better (IE<9)

Comment: @ErnieBob to include IE from version 8, use display:table, you can add table-layout:fixed so table doesn't grow over the width set.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `display: table` and `display: table-cell` would work well here.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.left,
.right,
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
}
.left {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  width: 60px;
}
.middle {
  background: green;
  /* no width needed */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```